# How do I turn off the lines coming off the spheres?

Tags: modeling

When I choose Wireframe Viewport Shading these lines come off of my spheres. It blocks my view of the rig.

What is this called? Is there a way to turn it off?

Wireframe:
[image: wireframe:]

Solid:

[image: Solid Mode:]

Comment: Are they relationship lines?  You can disable to display of relationship lines in the overlays dropdown.

Comment: I've tried that. Some lines went away. But not the sphere lines. The lines from the sphere are heading toward the origin.

Comment: Can you show solid mode?

Comment: I have edited the post to show solid mode.